# Change app icon background color in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to change the app icon background color?

My icon image is png with transparent background. When I launch the app in android the app background color is white, while in ios the background color is black.

Here is the icon in android:

[image]

And here is the icon in ios:

[image]

Here is the code snippet for android in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:label="R17 Group"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
 </application>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you want white color for both background? Can you include the code-snippet that you've tried for icon?

Comment: Yes, I want white color for both background. I have updated my question @YeasinSheikh

Comment: You can try with providing background color on asset image. Also you can follow [Change background color of flutter app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65391820/10157127)

Answer (score 1):

use flutter_launcher_icon package and customize your launcher icon yourself
**https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons**

Answer (score 0):

if you want a white background why not replace the transparent with white?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why don't you write in a comment instead of an answer? Since, this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by opening your project on Android Studio.

1. Right click on app
2. Click new
3. Image Asset
4. Click on background layer and change the color
5. Click on foreground layer and add your image to the path
6. Click next